# Are semilinear sets piecewise periodic?

Tags: nt.number-theory, lo.logic, formal-languages

I wanted to check my understanding of semilinear sets before I give a talk on them, and I haven't been able to find this exact perspective in any of the sources I've read through. Is it correct, and are there any sources that provide this perspective?

Given vectors $c, p_i$ in $\mathbb{N}^n$, $P = \{p_0,\ldots,p_n\}$, in addition to the linear set they form:

$$L(c;P) = \{c+\sum_i k_i p_i | k_i \in \mathbb{N}\}$$

We can also define the cone they form:

$$C(c;P) = \mathbb{N}^n \cap \{c + \sum_i r_i p_i | r_i \in [0,\infty)\}$$

We can then describe a periodic behavior to be tiled over this cone by picking out points in the unit parallelogram described by our vectors. Picking out a $C$:

$$C \subseteq \mathbb{N}^n \cap \{c + \sum_i r_i p_i | r_i \in [0,1)\}$$

Gives us the periodic set $$L(C;P) = \{c+\sum_i k_i p_i | k_i \in \mathbb{N}, c \in C\}$$

My understanding of semilinear sets (finite unions of linear sets) is that they are piecewise periodic where the pieces are finite unions of cones. That is, given a semilinear set $X$, one can partition $\mathbb{N}^n$ into finitely many pieces that are each finite unions of cones, such that $X$ agrees with a periodic set as above on that piece (with period set $P$ from the piece).

Is this correct? If not, can I repair it, perhaps by replacing the pieces with boolean combinations of cones? If so, can I strengthen it, perhaps by replacing the pieces with just cones?

---

Addendum: My goal here is to provide an alternate characterization of the semilinear sets to make their closure under boolean operations more intuitive.

I thought I would add a not fully rigorous argument that this is a valid characterization of the semi-linear sets in order to make it easier to verify/disprove. I would greatly appreciate any corrections to my intuitions.

First, I claim that boolean combinations of cones (sets of the form $C(c;P)$ as above) are finite unions of cones (keeping in mind that singletons are cones, so any finite set is trivially a finite union of cones). This is intuitively the case since boolean combinations of linear sets are finite unions of linear sets, and cones are just linear sets with a special "interior closure" property.

A linear set is periodic in its own cone, so every linear set has my piecewise periodic property (one piece: that cone). Intuitively, boolean combinations of piecewise periodic sets are piecewise periodic, as long as the available pieces are closed under boolean operations and the available periodic patterns are closed under boolean operations. So semilinear sets, being finite unions of linear sets should also have my piecewise periodic property.

In the other direction, since cones are semilinear, finite unions of cones are semilinear. Periodic patterns within given cones are semilinear (see $L(C;P)$ above). Any set that is piecewise periodic is just a boolean combination of pieces and periodic patterns, and thus, since the semilinear sets are closed under boolean operations, my piecewise periodic sets should be semilinear.

Comment: Any semilinear set is indeed a finite disjoint union of linear sets. Furthermore there is a disjoint union like this, where  each linear set $P$ has linearly independent generating vectors $p_i$  You could check the article Ito, R.: Every semilinear set is a finite union of disjoint linear sets. J. Comput. System Sci. 3.2, 221-231 (1969).

Comment: The stated theorem isn't enough for my needs, but perhaps the proof is. I think my claim would follow if the linear sets in Ito's construction are mutually disjoint either because their cones are disjoint or because they have the same periods and different starting constants. I'll keep working through the paper, but is this how the proof works?

Comment: You wouldn't be able to get disjoint cones even in one-dimensional case. Indeed, consider a semilinear set $A=\{3n+1,3n+2\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. If it would be possible to decompose it as you want, then there would be a linear set $L(c,P)$ containing a final segment of $A$. Thus for some $n$ both $3n+1-c$ and $3n+2-c$ are in $L(0,P)$ and hence there is some $a\in L(0,P)$ not divisible by 3. We thus see that one of the numbers $c,c+a,c+2a\in L(c,P)$  is divisible by 3 and hence is not in $A$, contradiction.

Comment: The set you provide is the periodic set $L(\{1,2\};3)$ over the cone $L(0;3)$. In my construction, I'm allowing arbitrary periodic behavior over each piece. My goal with my construction is to make it easier to see that the semilinear sets are closed under boolean operations: The complement of a piecewise periodic set is a piecewise periodic set with the same pieces, but complemented periodic behavior. The intersection of piecewise periodic sets has pieces that are boolean combinations of the initial pieces, and the intersection of two periodic patterns is intuitively periodic.